# gcc breaking rax value after function call

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm, intel

I am rewriting some C functions in ASM for practicing.
My `memset` function is setting `RAX` to the same address passed in the `RDI` register.
But gcc is extending the `AL`'s value with the `CDQE` instruction.

```
char super[] = "suuuuuuuuuuper";

res = memset(super, 't', 4);
printf("memset = {%s} (%p) res = %p\n", super, super, res);
```

Output :

```
memset = {ttttuuuuuuuper} (0x7fffffd30250) res = 0xffffffffffd30250
```

Then a segmentation fault would occur if I try to access the address stored in `res`.
I can just edit the binary file and replace the `CQDE` call with two `NOP` instructions, it will run perfectly.

But I was wondering if there's something else, such as a GCC flag to avoid that call ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the code calling `memset()` has seen a proper prototype for `memset()` so it knows that the function returns a `void*` instead of an `int`.

Of course you'll also need to pass the `-fno-builtin-memset` option to the compiler (or something equivalent) to make sure the compiler calls your function at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was about to try that !